# With quarto how can I right-left center align (justify) contents within a column in a two column display

Tags: quarto

I have a two column display in `quarto`.  What do I add to right-left center (justify) content within each of the columns?  Here is the basic code:

```
---
title: "uncentered"
---

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%"}
content
x
content
:::

::: {.column width="50%"}
y
content
y
:::

::::
```

From the [pandoc docs](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#additional-columns-attributes-in-beamer) I see I can use `align=center` in beamer but I just want a basic html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to tweak things in html, you can use css rules as a last resort.

Try this

````
---
title: "uncentered"
format: html
engine: knitr
---


```{css echo=FALSE}
.column {
text-align: center;
}
```


:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%"}

content

x

content
:::

::: {.column width="50%"}

y

content

y
:::

::::
````

**Also take note of that `engine: knitr` in yaml. Since Here the very first thing was used a css code, Quarto will try to render this file using jupyter engine.** So I have specified `engine: knitr` just to be in  a safe side.

Comment: Thank you.  That works.  Does this mean that the `.column` is a css class?.  I thought it was an instruction being passed to PANDOC to create the columns. Do I have that wrong?  It bugs me that I can't tell how .columns inside of the fenced div block is being processed.  Have you found a way to tell what is being converted into a CSS class vs. a pandoc instruction?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how `.columns` get handled in other doc formats, but when rendered in html documents, `.columns`,  `.column` both are acting as a css class. And you can always see the internals of your html documents by opening that in a  browser and right click and then inspect